# What's the standard for returning digital paperwork: scanned or digital?

Tags: professionalism

I'm quite young and this is the first time dealing with this kind of stuff, just wondering how should I handle digital paperwork that is sent to me?

I received a W-8BEN-E in pdf format, does the company expect me to print it out physically, fill it in with pen then scan it? Or should I use Adobe Reader or some pdf tool to insert text and keep the text selectable?

I'm asking because I want to make a good first impression and they might want details in a selectable format (rather than a scanned image), I don't want to hassle them.

Comment: Have you tried asking them? We can only guess - some companies prefer one way or the other, some don't care at all.

Comment: Alternatively pick one option and say you are happy to do the other if needed. Considering you are emailing and not mailing it, you can turn it around very quickly. In my experience if it's a PDF then they expect you to fill in by hand and scan, but could go either way.

Comment: While I appreciate your acceptance of my answer Dale, I want to point out that we generally encourage you not to accept an answer too quickly. You may want to give other people a chance to submit an answer as well and accepting early tends to discourage other people from replying. You are free to change or remove the mark-as-answered tick at any time and you may want to do so and wait [one or two days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/260382) before evaluating the answers you received and accepting the one that you found the most helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Print it, sign it, and scan it. The standard practice when it comes to signing PDF forms that are sent to you is to print them out and return a scan. If they've gone through the trouble of allowing you to electronically sign something they'll tell you. Employers usually won't bother for the type of form you got.

If the form doesn't require a signature and is set up to be filled in from your PDF reader you *used* to be able to do either, but that's changing somewhat. In a "modern" organization like an IT company they'll typically expect their employees to know enough to fill out a form digitally. Printing it out may come across as quaint. But usually if they prefer or require that you send back an editable file they'll tell you as they're used to people who aren't tech-savvy getting it wrong.

You get the occasional person who signs a form like this digitally in a photo editor because they dislike printing a form out just to send back a scan or because they simply lack access to a printer, but that is something I wouldn't recommend. Whether those signatures are valid is often a legal gray area and HR usually frowns on the practice just because it's outside the norm.

And as a tl;dr:

[image]

Comment: If the PDF is intentionally editable and doesn't require a signature, I just fill it in and return it digitally.  If it's read-only or needs a scribble, I'll print it out to fill in and scan to return.

Comment: This is good but leaves off one option that I often see - the form is editable but the signature line is not. For those I'll fill out the form digitally and then print and scan the signature page. That way you don't have to worry about how legible your handwriting is.

Comment: @DavidK You're right, I figured that was up to the person's preference and I could get away with one fewer action in the flowchart but on second thought that loop back to the top is kind of ugly. :) Adjusted.

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes that the PDF you receive is editable. If it is not, filling out the PDF will be less convenient, so it is unclear if it makes sense to do it. In that case, you can do whatever seems more convenient.

---

You should **fill out everything electronically except the parts that require filling out by hand**.

Unless you have to provide a signature (signing electronically is a legal gray area, as mentioned by Lilienthal) or have very specific reasons to fill something out by hand (like including sketches that are inconvenient to produce electronically), filling out forms electronically is the better way. This is because **filling out by hand has no upside**.

On the other hand, if you fill out electronically,

- The receiver can copy and paste
- The result will be more readable
- It is faster (you do not have to print and scan)
- The file size will be smaller, making it more convenient to send by e-mail

For these reasons, even if a document requires a signature, I usually fill out everything electronically except the signature, and then print-sign-scan. If your scanner can do OCR, the parts you filled in electronically will then still be copyable.

Comment: +1 Though I'll point out that you can digitally sign a document without using the photoshop method. At our organization you use a smartcard and PIN, which is essentially the same as digitally signing your email.